# retrieve last 6 bits from an integer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to fetch last 6 bits of a integer or Uint32. For example if I have a value of 183, I need last six bits which will be `110 111` ie `55`.

I have written a small piece of code, but it's not behaving as expected. Could you guys please point out where I am making a mistake?

```
int compress8bitTolessBit( int value_to_compress, int no_of_bits_to_compress )
{
    int ret = 0;
    while(no_of_bits_to_compress--)
    {
        std::cout << " the value of bits "<< no_of_bits_to_compress << std::endl;
        ret >>= 1;
        ret |= ( value_to_compress%2 );
        value_to_compress /= 2;
    }
    return ret;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int val = compress8bitTolessBit( 183, 5 );

    std::cout <<" the value is "<< val << std::endl;
      system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the unnecessarily complex code, what do you think `ret >>= 1` is going to achieve. Also, you might wish to consider what will happen if the passed in number is negative.

Comment: Thanks everyone , for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have entered the realm of binary arithmetic. C++ has built-in operators for this kind of thing. The act of "getting certain bits" of an integer is done with an "AND" binary operator.

```
    0101 0101
AND 0000 1111
    ---------
    0000 0101
```

In C++ this is:

```
int n = 0x55 & 0xF;
// n = 0x5
```

So to get the right-most 6 bits,

```
int n = original_value & 0x3F;
```

And to get the right-most N bits,

```
int n = original_value & ((1 << N) - 1);
```

Here is more information on

- [Binary arithmetic operators in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Bitwise_operators)
- [Binary operators in general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators)

Answer (score 7):

I don't get the problem, can't you just use bitwise operators? Eg

```
u32 trimmed = value & 0x3F;
```

This will keep just the 6 least significant bits by using the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr:

```
int val = x & 0x3F;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do object to the txt jargon (or is it leet-speek?)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just pasting a line of code isn't really helpful to the OP. It would be much better with some explanation. If the OP knew what `operator&` did, he wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: +1 Writing simple code that solves the problem can lead the reader to explore and learn more. It's not always necessary to spoon-feed information to people.

Comment: To be fair, the question itself is pretty bad (at least it's way too localized), so indeed the spirit of making SO a resource for problem solving is a bit lost on this question, so all bets are off as far as site policy goes...

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = input & ((1 << (no_of_bits_to_compress + 1) - 1)
```

This one calculates the (n+1)th power of two: `1 << (no_of_bits_to_compress + 1)` and subtracts 1 to get a mask with all `n` bits set.

Answer (score 1):

The last k bits of an integer A.

```
1. A % (1<<k); // simply A % 2^k
2. A - ((A>>k)<<k);
```

The first method uses the fact that the last k bits is what is trimmed after doing k right shits(divide by 2^k).